# Diagnosing Linux to Windows C++ port of console only program with only standard libraries

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio, gcc, porting

I've written a program that translates text to XML, and it compiles without warnings and works exactly as intended using GCC on 64-bit Linux.  It uses only standard library functions and an open source library designed for use in Visual Studio.

Here are the includes:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
#include "rapidxml.hpp"
```

Now, it also compiles without warnings in Visual Studio 2017, but when I go to run it, it seems to sit stuck in a loop for a bit then crash.  The debug message said debug assertion failed for "xstring".  "xstring" does not appear in my code.

I've read numerous articles on porting from Linux to Windows, but none of the advice seems to apply.  I'm not using non-standard libraries, not reading in files generated in Linux, and I've literally pasted the code into a "c++ console program" template in Visual Studio, targeted the machine it's on, and compiled.  There's no bit flipping, XOR masks, or anything like that going on, just a ton of string operations, and all the errors are coming from MS DLLs.  I don't compare characters to ASCII numeric values or anything like that, only to other characters.  I have to assume a character typed on Windows, like ')', would be the same as itself on Windows.

If I run the program in the debugger, the program gives me console output that I started it without specifying a target file and exits, as it should.  Whether the program is compiled for x64 or x86 makes no difference except for which Microsoft DLL that I didn't include throws an exception.

I turned on all Microsoft warnings and the only thing I got additionally was that

```
std::isdigit(*itr_str)
```

requires unsigned char and was called with char.

Is isdigit() not usable on a character from a std::string under Windows?  Right now that's my only clue. I haven't found anyone claiming this is the case online while searching, though.

I don't actually know anything about Visual Studio, I just have a subscription to do very minor code updates and maintenance for work. I also only get about 10 mins a day free to mess around with VS at work.  Until now, anything I wrote at home has been just dumped into VS2017 and compiled in the same manner, and run without issue.

Would trying for cross-compilation from Linux be my best option, or is there something simple I should look at first?

Comment: Did you try stopping execution while it is "stuck" and observing the stack to see where it is "stuck"? It sounds like your code has UB, but ofc we cannot debug that from here.

Comment: Selecting "debug" gave me some warning about how it could not be debugged, and I had to get back to work so I didn't investigate further.

Comment: It's almost certainly a build or environment configuration problem or a bug corrupting memory that's luckily avoided in the Linux build and not in the one for Windows. In either (any) case, you've provided not nearly enough information. How is anyone to debug your code or build config with no code or build config?

Comment: Alright, I will read up about build configs in VS, and give it a shot tomorrow.  I'm kind of in the same situation you as a reader are, where I know there's a bunch of stuff that COULD be looked into, but am prevented from doing so by factors beyond my control.  Eventually if they don't give me time, these small project will come together into a program that can do the job of several employees but only runs on Linux, which they won't use.

Comment: You might try compiling on MingW32, which is an implementation more like Linux. Microsoft’s implementation of the standard library does have some bugs, but it's more likely to be a non-portable assumption in your code. In particular, does your XML library support Unicode, and if so, how?

Comment: What do you mean" targeted the machine it's on"?

Comment: VS has a many debugging options. Besides stepping instructions, a very usefull feature is too pause a program when it is runnig Debug -> Break All. Then You can open up Debug -> Windows -> Call Stack to see where your program is at.

Comment: To add command line parameters for a debugged program - open up the project properties, And in Configuration Properties -> Debugging, Command Arguments can be specified. Just be careful which build You specifing it for - Configuration: which can be either Realease or Debug.

Comment: This is what I observed once in VS2013 (although this might happen on other platforms/compilers as well). `std::string::operator[]` provides `char`. If used with `isdigit()` (and friends) it is converted to `int`. For non-ASCII characters (with value > 127), this becomes negative due to sign extension. As these `cctype` functions use a look-up table internally, negative index is out of range (and Bamm!). A possible fix is to insert a `(unsigned char)` cast for every arg. of type `char` which is passed to `isdigit()` (and friends). This is especially important if applied to UTF-8 strings.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions.  I'll try Robert's first to see if I can get any useful clues.  My entire character space is A-Z, 0-9, and the symbols on the numeric row of a US keyboard.  What I mean by "targeting the machine it's on" is choosing the correct SDK level and hitting "retarget" which seems to make VS happy.  I'm sure there's a default setting somewhere where I can set VS to use the SDK installed, but I use it so infrequently I haven't spent time to set anything up.